Is a strict fundamental domain in a simply connected complex simply connected itself?
Let $G$ be a group acting on a simplicial (or just combinatorial CW-) complex by simplicial morphisms without inversion. Assume that this action has a strict fundamental domain $Y\subseteq X$, meaning that $Y$ is a subcomplex of $X$ and thus the quotient space is isomorphic to $Y$. Assume that $X$ is simply connected. Then, is $Y$ simply connected?
In the 1-dimensional case, this is true, as any subset of a tree must be simply connected. But what about in other dimensions?

Any connected subset of a tree is simply connected.

Yes, this is true: simple connectivity of $X$ implies simple connectivity of $Y$. With one caveat: the concept of a "strict" fundamental domain should be slightly strengthened.
To prepare for the proof, what the concept of "strict fundamental domain" ought to say is this:

Every orbit of the $G$ action on $X$ contains a unique point of the subcomplex $Y$.

In that situation the quotient map $q : X \to Y$ may then be defined so that it takes each orbit of the $G$-action to the unique point of $Y$ contained in that orbit. This map $q$ has the advantage that it is a retract in the topological category, meaning a continuous map such that for each $y \in Y$ we have $q(y)=y$.
For the proof, consider a continuous function $f : S^1 \to Y$. We have to prove that $f$ has a continuous extension $D^2 \mapsto Y$. Composing with inclusion $Y \hookrightarrow X$, let $f^X : S^1 \to X$ be the composition. Since $X$ is simply connected, $f^X$ extends to a continuous function $F : D^2 \to X$. By composing with the quotient map we obtain
$$q \circ F : D^2 \to Y
$$
Applying our hypothesis that $q$ is a retract, it follows that
$$(q \circ F) \mid S^1 = f
$$
and therefore $q \circ F$ is the desired continuous extension of $f$.
This proof extends to prove something more general:

For any retract $X \mapsto Y$, the inclusion $Y \hookrightarrow X$ induces an injection $\pi_1 Y \hookrightarrow \pi_1 X$.


I'll add that this solution begs the question of whether my notion of "strict fundamental domain" is strictly stronger than yours. At the moment I'm unsure about this question, but I'll post this answer anyway.

Marvelous! I had not realized that it came down to such a basic topological result. As for the notion of strict fundamental domain, yes, this is what I meant. The condition you added is that of "fundamental domain", which I just assumed and I only stressed out the "strict" part which is what I wrote. Indeed the strictness is not really necessary for this result. I only added the condition because I'm interested in having an isomorphic orbit space.Thank you very very much!

There is one extra subtle point. It is important for this argument that $Y$ be closed; without that, the retract map will not be continuous. But that is guaranteed by your hypothesis that $Y$ is an actual subcomplex.
